# How to control Wireshark using python? How to click/press the buttons in Wireshark using python

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, wireshark, pcap

I want to capture pcap (logs) in Wireshark using python,  so basically I have to launch Wireshark though Python script which can be achieved using subprocess.call() or os.system() or os.startfile().
Now how to select the interface [ Wi-Fi,Ethernet] using python and after selecting interface how to save the capture using python?
(click on the stop capturing packets button in taskbar -> click on 'file' in taskbar -> click on 'save as'-> give the filename -> give the location-> save）

I don't want to use pyshark, i want to capture packet using Wireshark only .

Thank you

Comment: I sense an X Y problem. But take a look at this [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) and [dumpcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html). UI is meant for a User, Not to be manipulated programmatically.

Comment: I have one more question, we can capture only http traffic using Wireshark(tshark,dumpcap) right. I want to capture https traffic also using fiddler. So how to achieve that?

Comment: tshark and dumpcap capture all traffic, not just HTTPS. See answer and please mark as accepted and upvote.

Comment: I am so sorry I can't see the option to accept the answer,

Comment: Actually I am very new to the stackoverflow

Comment: I got it, thank you so much for helping me out JBis,you are awesome.

Comment: Glad I can help! Good luck with your troubles. Also, if you found the answer helpful, please upvote it by pressing the up arrow on the left of my answer to upvote it. Also, since you are new, I encourage you to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: Yes I want to upvote Cir

Comment: Yes I want to upvote but when I am clicking on the button it is saying" votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded "something like that

Comment: Ah. I forgot. To upvote you need 15 rep. Don't worry about it. You will be there in no time! :) Until then, continue to ask good questions and maybe answer some.

Comment: Ok, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense an X Y problem. UI is meant for a User, not to be manipulated programmatically.

Instead take a look at....

### **Wireshark Tools**

[tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

> `tshark` - Dump and analyze network traffic
>
> TShark is a network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture packet data
>   from a live network, or read packets from a previously saved capture
>   file, either printing a decoded form of those packets to the standard
>   output or writing the packets to a file. TShark's native capture file
>   format is pcap format

[dumpcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html)

> `dumpcap` - Dump network traffic
>
> Dumpcap is a network traffic dump tool. It lets you capture packet
>   data from a live network and write the packets to a file. Dumpcap's
>   default capture file format is pcapng format. When the -P option is
>   specified, the output file is written in the pcap format.

### **Fiddler** (See comments)

[fiddler.exe](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/commandlineparams)

> Fiddler supports a variety of command line arguments that control
>   various options:
>
> Fiddler Command-Line Help
>    Usage:
>
> ```
> fiddler.exe [options] [FileToLoad.saz]
> ```

### **Other**

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org) (Most of the above are based on this or use this)

> This is the official web site of tcpdump, a powerful command-line
>   packet analyzer; and libpcap, a portable C/C++ library for network
>   traffic capture.

Comment: You solved my problem but still please let me know  if you know how to control other tools using python.I mean how To click buttons in the tools using python.

Comment: @AayanArora I do not know python enough to give you a definitive answer but it's going to depend on the OS and it's never going to work properly. UI is just not meant for that. If you must, use a Mac and Automator. It's built in and will be able to click buttons, move mouse, just about what ever, but again it doesn't always work perfectly.

Comment: pywinauto is a general purpose GUI automation tool.

Comment: There is also scapy Python package that can send and capture network packets. It’s perfect except GPLv2 license and less number of protocols supported than WireShark.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend nice project that is practically a wrapper around tshark and written in python - [pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark). It is easy to use and you can play with pcaps or live streams.